# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'tuple'

Tags: python, statistics

I am trying to calculate the best-adjusted R^2, but encountered an issue

```
# your code here

# mpg is the response variable, while others are predictors
feature = df[['cylinders', 'displacement', 'horsepower', 'weight', 'acceleration', 'model_year', 'origin']]
response = df['mpg']

feature = sm.add_constant(feature)

model = sm.OLS(response,feature).fit()
predictions = model.predict(feature)

print_model = model.summary()
print(print_model)

#Create a function that will do backwards elimination and finds the best adjusted R^2
def create_SLR_model(df, response, feature):
    model = response + "~" + feature
    SLR_model = smf.ols(model, data=df)
    return(SLR_model)

def find_the_best_model(df, response):
    current_best = ("Placeholder", 0)
    for col in df.columns.drop(response):
        calculate_Rsquared = create_SLR_model(df, response, col).fit().rsquared
        if calculate_Rsquared > current_best[1]:
            current_best = (col, current_best)
    return current_best

best_model = find_the_best_model(df, "mpg")

best_predictor = best_model[0]
best_r_squared = best_model[1]
print(best_predictor, best_r_squared)
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjFLu.png)

I would like some pinpoint since I am a beginner Python programmer, and would like some help, thanks.

Comment: Please post code, data, and **results** as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: `calculate_Rsquared` is a numpy array. Why are you trying to compare it with a tuple containing a string and number? How is that comparison supposed to work?

Comment: Actually I figured out my issue, there is a logic error: should be                                     
 if calculate_Rsquared > current_best[1]:
            current_best = (col, calculate_Rquared)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `calculate_Rsquared` is an array and not just a single number.

for the variable `calculate_Rsquared`, try indexing the variable to get the value you want from it to compare to your `current_best[1]`

or to test this, run:

```
calculate_Rsquared = create_SLR_model(df, response, col).fit().rsquared
```

in your terminal with whatever variables `df, response and col` is filled in
and see what `calculate_Rsquared` actually is

Best of luck! :)

Comment: Actually I figured out my issue, there is a logic error: should be if calculate_Rsquared > current_best[1]: current_best = (col, calculate_Rquared)